# Align Button to right of progress bar

Tags: css, html, css-float

Can anybody please help me align the Cancel button to the right of the progress bar? I've tried float and display inline with no success, and I'm out of ideas.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="progress progress-striped active" style="width: 500px; margin: 0px auto; height: 40px;">
    <div id="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:20%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline;"><button class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button></div>
</div>
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wFLw5/) of it demonstrating my problem:

Comment: as like this http://jsfiddle.net/wFLw5/2/

Comment: looks like this is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/wFLw5/4/

Comment: +1 don't know why someone down voted this perfectly good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `float:left` to both the loading bar and the cancel button, plus some slight css to align the cancel button better such as `top` and `left`:

[UPDATED EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wFLw5/6/)

Comment: Now the progress bar is no longer center aligned though ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try to this  Define `pull-left` of your **div as like this**

```
<br><br><br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="progress progress-striped active pull-left" style="width: 500px; margin: 0px auto; height: 40px; margin-right:10px;"><div id="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:20%;"></div></div>

    <button class="btn btn-warning pull-left">Cancel</button>

</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wFLw5/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

You are using Twitter Bootstrap so : **Use the bootstrap class** instead of your hard style.

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/wFLw5/1/

**HTML** :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10 progress progress-striped active"><div id="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:20%;"></div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-2"><button class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think The Little Pig is most correct in suggesting you use the actual Bootstrap styles. However, you can align the cancel button to the right of the progress bar by setting `display:inline-block;` on both elements, and then offsetting the cancel button.